# Is the Big-0 complexity same with looping and simply printing?

Tags: arrays, big-o

I am learning about BIG-O and got confused below:

```
     int arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

-- simple print

```
    print(arr[0])
    print(arr[1])
    print(arr[2])
    print(arr[3])
    print(arr[4])
```

-- loop - BIG-O O(n)

```
    for i in length(arr) {
            print( arr[i] )
    }
```

would the simple print also give me O(n) or O(1) ?

Comment: The loop would be considered to be `O(n)`, and the print statement does not change the complexity.

Comment: The first is O(n) in terms of the required development time.

Comment: @Dúthomhas no it is not, it shows a fundamental lack of understanding of what O is for. And such a questions gets asked like 10 times every day.

Comment: @luk2302 OP is asking to fix his lack of understanding. If the question is so commonly asked, then link the dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big-O is all about *loops* and *growth*.

If you have a fixed ***n*** then it is O(1) to print them — it will always take the same amount of time (***n***=5) to print ***n***=5 items.

But for some *variable* ***n***, it takes more time the larger ***n*** gets, so it becomes O(n).

<s>If you are talking about *storage*, then an array of ***n*** items is O(n), even for fixed ***n***=5.</s>

Context matters. This context was me being stupid. O(5) is O(1).

Comment: Thank you. I will study in more depth to understand more.

Comment: Why would the properties of big-O change when we talk about storage? *O(5)* space complexity is still the same class as *O(1)*.

Comment: Though I admit my brain is being stupid right now. I think I have to agree with you. O(5) is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is constant (*O(1)*), because you are accessing a value by index, and indexed access of an array is typically a constant-time operation.

Your loop is *O(n)*, as you guessed. So your code in total would also be *O(n)*, since the loop performs a constant action.

As a disclaimer, this can get more complex depending on our computation model and assumptions. For instance, not all computation model assume constant-time random access, and you could argue that printing a number also depends on the size of that number and turns out to be *O(log n)*. But I think that in the scope of your question, you don't need to worry about this.

Comment: Indexing or printing is generally an amortized write-off when talking about Big-O over any indexable/printable list of items. The index or print operation itself may have O(n) (or worse) behavior, but over _all **n**_ we take it as O(1). Otherwise you are mixing different _**n**s_.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I was rather referring to the fact that an integer *n* requires *O(log n)* bits to represent it and so writing it onto an "output tape" will require at least this time. I suppose in true asymptotic analysis, you can't get around this. But in actual programming on a real computer, yeah printing is constant time and so is random access. And I think this whole discussion is beyond the scope of OP anyway :)